# computing modular arithmetic of huge numbers in matlab (RSA)

Tags: matlab, rsa, modulo

I am trying to perform an RSA encryption/decryption using modulo function in matlab.
The problem is that I cannot do mod(x,y) when x is 50+ integer digits and y is also 50+ integer digits.

Is there a function in matlab that can do mod of huge int prime numbers?

Also is there a way to store really huge numbers in a variable such as:
x=p^e where p and e are 50+ integers.

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, I'm guessing you'll want to look into the binary expansion method of modular exponentiation, as in [this Wikipedia section.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method)

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you need arbitrary-precision arithmetic.  Mathworks offers a Multiple Precision Toolbox:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6446

Don't know how it works, and I don't work for Mathworks either.